# Проблемы с ограничением IP

Tags: mysql, firewall

Требуется сделать whitelist IP, которые смогут подключаться к mysql (взаимодействовать с портом 3306 (серисом mysql)).

Можно привилегии настроить конечно на самом mysql, но я хочу соединения закрывать до взаимодействия с mysql, а т.е. прописать правила в firewall.

Как я делаю:

Добавляю сервис:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=mysql --permanent
```

Затем добавляю правила:

```
firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address="REMOTE_IP" service name="mysql" accept' --permanent
```

И перезагружаю:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Но, подключаясь с стороннего IP, допустим через telnet:

```
telnet IP 3306
```

Соединение сразу не сбрасывается, а высвечивается:

> Версия (Набор непонятных символов) mysql_native_password

Т.е. firewall не выполнил требуемых действий, а пропустил.

Comment: А где правило, которое запрещает соединение всем «неразрешенным» ip?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Подсказали что просто удалить сервис mysql и все заработает и заработало. Так как добавление сервиса открывает порты для всех, а я добавлением правила 'rich' затем еще раз открывал для определенных IP.